# formからPOST送信される階層化された値をパラメータとして取得したい。

Tags: java, html, http, google-app-engine, servlet

お世話になっております。

環境
Eclipse 4.4
GAE/J 1.9.30
Servlet 2.5
※ServletFileUploadを使用しています。

```
<form action="/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <fieldset name="child">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="age">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

このようなformを送信する際にServlet側でパラメータを受け取っています
Servletでは

```
public class Parent {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Child child;
}
public class Child {
   private String name;
   private int age;
}
```

このような2つのデータクラスを持っています。

そこでformのnameとageをParentのフィールドに、fieldset内のnameとageを
Childのフィールドに格納し、ParentのchildにChildを格納したいと考えています。

Servletではリクエストパラメータを順に取り出し、リフレクションを使用することでParentの
フィールドにはセットできている状況です。
しかしChildのフィールドにリクエストパラメータをセットするにはどのようにしたらいいのでしょうか？

ParentからChildのフィールドを取得できない&できたとして同じname属性なのでどれがchild
のname属性を持ったinputの値かわからない状況です。

パラメータを1つずつ取り出す際にfieldset内のnameまたはageだと判断できるといいのですが。。

階層化と表現したのは
name, age, child: {name, age} 
のようなイメージで取得したいためです。
またここには定義していないですが、画像の送信も行うのでmultipartである必要があります。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

実際に送信されるデータを確認してみるとわかりますが、`fieldset`要素によるグルーピングはデータ構造には反映されません。それぞれの`input`要素で`name`属性がユニークになるよう修正してください。

Comment: 早速回答いただきありがとうございます。
fieldsetのパラメータをpost送信して取得はできていませんでしたが、方法としてはやはりないのですね。

パラメータ名もChildのフィールド名もユニークにして対応するとして、リフレクションでどのようにParentからChildのフィールドを取得する方法を探してみます。